# Select value from string

Tags: c#

I have this code that is telling a system to open the tab "Employee" in a WPF client.

```
class Startup
{
    public void Init()
    {
        var screen = Tabs.Employee;
        Tabs.OpenTab(screen, null);
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
string screenName = "Employee";
var screen = Tabs.screenName;
```

In order to be able to pass the Employee as a value.

The Tabs class looks like this:

```
public class Tabs
{
    public delegate void AddDockTab(string controlName, object argument = null);

    public const string Empty = "Empty";
    public const string Employee = "Employee";
    public const string Customer = "Customer";

    private static UnicontaTabs utab;
    public static event AddDockTab OnAddDockTab;

    protected Tabs()
    {
        utab = this;
    }
    public static void OpenTab(string controlName, object argument)
    {
        if (utab != null)
        {
            utab.AddTab(controlName, argument);
        }
    }
    protected virtual void AddTab(string controlName, object argument)
    {
        Tabs.OnAddDockTab?.Invoke(controlName, argument);
    }
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetControlNames()
    {
        FieldInfo[] fields = typeof(Tabs).GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        return fields.Select((FieldInfo f) => f.Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: How about `Tabs.OpenTab(screenName, null);`? The value of `Tabs.Employee` is just `"Employee"` after all? Or do you not have control over `Tabs`, and the constant's value might change at some point in the future?

Comment: What's wrong with `Tabs.OpenTab(screen, null);`?